# Does accepting lottery winnings count as benefiting from a miracle?

Tags: halacha, miracle, parnassah-livelihood, gambling

The gemara in Nedarim 50 (and many other places) discusses how various rabbis refused to benefit at all from miracles, turning down gold and jewels, warehouses of grain, etc.

In the gemara, finding buried treasure is somehow classified as miraculous, even though it was already in existence prior to that point. That it occurred to rabbi Gamda was part of the miracle. This suggests that "naturally occurring phenomena" still fall under the rubric of miracles when sufficiently unlikely, akin to Maimonides' general interpretation of the miraculous being a confluence of natural phenomena occurring in just the right manner at the exact time needed.

The probability of winning is deliberately engineered to be in one to several hundred million (175 million for the powerball, ~259 million for the mega-millions). If we take this attitude toward miracles to be an optimal level of behavior, would the long odds on winning preclude such individuals from accepting lottery jackpot winnings as the product/benefit of a miracle?

Comment: I would say no it's not a miracle...

Comment: This is not outside the realms of nature. Someone was going to win eventually.

Comment: @user6591 finding buried treasure is somehow miraculous, even though it was already in existence prior to that point. That it occurred to rabbi Akiva was part of the miracle. This suggests that "naturally occurring phenomena" still fall under the rubric of miracles when sufficiently unlikely, akin to Maimonides' interpretation of what a miracle is.

Comment: @Tim see my edits for further explanation of my reasoning. If you can provide sources, I'd certainly be willing to accept a "no" as an answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is buying a lottery ticket a lack of faith?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14853/is-buying-a-lottery-ticket-a-lack-of-faith)

Comment: @Yishai not at all! This doesn't discuss any implications on faith. Only whether there is potentially a threshold that is crossed which makes winning the lottery miraculous.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, the crux of the question is "how does *hashkafa* view buying a lottery ticket?". I suppose you could draw a distinction, in that the crux of your question is "how does *hashkafa* view keeping the winnings of a lottery ticket?", and I admit that I was 51/49 on my vote, but in the end it was 51 towards it being a duplicate. Perhaps no one else will agree with me.

Comment: @Yishai to the contrary -your linked question is asking about *** buying a second ticket*** being a display of a lack of faith. I'm saying the *** winnings*** might be considered profiting off a miracle. Two VERY different questions, imho.

Comment: You are misreading the other question. It asserts that buying two is a problem and asks if buying one is OK anyway. The purpose of buying one is to keep the winnings. By the way, how would you feel about keeping the $2 prizes. Is your question only about the jackpot?

Comment: @Yishai an interesting caveat. One might argue that since the probability is so high of winning smaller amounts (greater than a 1% chance) that they wouldn't fall under the rubric of a miracle. But it's a valid question.

Comment: @Isaac Am I missing something? Where in the gemara on 50 do you see Rabi Akiva rejecting his riches?

Comment: @user6591 you are correct, I misspoke. It was rabbi gamda on 50b. There's a similar story in chagigah I think about brachot coming to that which is hidden (poor rabbi bought grain for daughter's wedding). In both cases (and in others), they gave away their wealth so as not to benefit.

Comment: I still don't see Rav Gamda refusing to accept the money the monkey found. All I see is the sailors giving it to him even though they didn't have to.

Comment: @user6591 Many of the meforashim interpret the story differently, saying that Rav Gamda refused the money as a midat chassidut rather than the sailors offering money to him out of kindness - the point was that R'Gamda didn't NEED the money - Hashem would supply it for him, and EVEN SO R'Gamda wasn't interested in benefitting off the miracle Hashem performed for him. Regardless, the story shows that such an occurance is considered miraculous despite being "naturally occuring."

Comment: I'm curious which mipharshim you are referring to. But even if that is so, there is a big difference between a bizarre occurrence which leads one to recognize providence, and a lottery which by default had to land on someone.

Comment: @user6591 I will be doing chazzara of that daf shortly, and will endeavor to update the question with names. If you want to listen yourself, it's R'Leibowitz on YU Torah who discusses the issue.

Comment: @user6591 Top of 50a has R'Yehudah refusing to benefit from ma'aseh nisim (gold found under his mat in his house) cf Ran there, as well as Tosfos, Rosh, and Ben Yehoyada.

Comment: @Isaac ah., finally:) But you make it sound like he had never moved his mattress before. That is doubtful. There is however a Maharsha(?) somewhere who differentiates between a tzadik and a tzadik gamur. When a nes happens for a tzadik it is minakeh zichuyosav, whereas a nes for a tzadik gamur is not. He uses this to explain why some personalities relied on miraculous occurrences, and some not. But I don't recall where it is.

Comment: If you're asking in theory, then if be inclined to say it's not a miracle. If you actually won, then I'd say you can't use it, rather, I'll deal with the money